# TFS 2010 MSBuild: After dll in Binaries folder

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I'm currently using the AfterBuild target to extend my build script but at that point the dll for the project hasn't been placed in the Binaries folder.

What target will run after the dll has been placed in the Binaries folder?

Comment: You should run your build script with the /verbosity:diag switch and search for the AfterBuild target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking in the context of TeamBuild (you tagged it TFS), here's a [relevant MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337604%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)